# Prevent imported libraries from using my logging-configuration file

Tags: java, logging, graphstream

**Hostile takeover of my logger !!**

TL:DR imported library is using my logger's **logging.properties** file.

In order to keep track of everything that happens in my project, I implemented a custom logger class using `java.utils.logging`, with a nice simple configuration file "**logging.properties**":

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level= ALL


java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = server/java/data/logs/myOwnLog%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 20000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = server/java/src/main/java/controller/utils/logs/LineFormat.java

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL



com.journaldev.files = SEVERE
```

Now after adding it, for some reason, one of my imported libraries - `GraphStream` start to use my configuration file.
Which means I get thier logs printed to my console and saved in log files in the location and with the name I defined in the configuration file.

I thought maybe there was a conflict of names with there configuration file but it wasn't it.

Any ideas?

first 3 lines are my logs and the rest are belongs to `GraphStream`.
[image: first 3 lines are my logs and the rest are belongs to GraphStream]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how logging in Java works: anything can attempt to write logs, and if you have configured the logging framework that it's trying to use, you'll get its messages.

The way to stop seeing messages third-party libraries is to disable them in your logging configuration (or, alternatively, disable everything except your own classes) by changing the level at which they report.

I don't use `java.util.logging`, but by reading the docs it appears that you could include a configuration line like this to turn off a third-party package:

```
com.thirdparty.level = OFF
```

Or alternatively, default everything to `OFF` and set your packages to `DEBUG`:

```
.level = OFF
com.mycompany.level=DEBUG
```